# How to run queue work on Laravel with docker?

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I create a docker setup on my Laravel project using sail.
În my project I use jobs and I want when I run `docker-compose up` to start the command `php artisan queue:work`. In my docker-compose.yml I defined an service `php-queue` like this:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
    php-queue:
        restart: always
        image: sail-8.0/app:latest
        command: 'php artisan queue:work'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:5.7'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
          retries: 3
          timeout: 5s

    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "ping" ]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

when I run `docker-compose up` in docker desktop it shows this error:

```
error: failed switching to "php": unable to find user php: no matching entries in passwd file
```

what I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Your query involves integrating Laravel Sail's workflow, specifically [`sail up`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#starting-and-stopping-sail), with queue processing.

[Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#introduction) is a light command-line interface for interacting with Laravel's default Docker development environment. When you run `sail up`, it is essentially a wrapper around `docker-compose up`, but with Sail-specific configurations.

To make sure `php artisan queue:listen` (or `queue:work`) is executed automatically when you run `sail up`, you will need to modify the `docker-compose.yml` file used by Sail. That file orchestrates your Docker containers, including the Laravel application and other services like MySQL and Redis.

- Add a service to your `docker-compose.yml` that runs [`php artisan queue:listen`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#the-queue-work-command). That can be done similarly to the `php-queue` service you have defined, but with an adjustment for compatibility with Sail.
- Customize the Sail service to run the queue worker. That might involve extending the existing Docker configuration used by Sail to include the queue worker.

Your `docker-compose.yml` would be:

```yaml
services:
    # other services 

    laravel.test:
        # existing configuration 
    
    # Define a new service for the queue worker
    queue:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        command: 
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - "php /var/www/html/artisan queue:listen"
```

That would add a `queue` service that is specifically configured to work within the Laravel Sail environment.
When you run `sail up`, this service will start along with the other services and begin processing jobs using `php artisan queue:listen`.

Answer (score 1):

change `command: 'php artisan queue:work'` to `command: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'php artisan queue:work'` thats should work

Also this could help you :)
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#executing-sail-commands

###### Running Artisan commands locally...

php artisan queue:work

###### Running Artisan commands within Laravel Sail...

sail artisan queue:work

Comment: now it shows me this error: `error: failed switching to "/bin/sh": unable to find user /bin/sh: no matching entries in passwd file
`

Comment: you are trying to run command inside container. So meaby for debug purpose try to not run command on container start and try to go inside the conatiner with docker-compose php-queue exec sh

I have not used sail but docs suggest to run command as https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#executing-sail-commands
so i suppose you can not exec php artisan directly

Answer (score 1):

The Docker container is not able to find the user `php`. This is because the `php-queue` service tries to run the command `php artisan queue:work` as the `php` user, which doesn't exist in the Docker image.

To fix this, you can use the `user` directive in your `docker-compose.yml` file to specify the user that should run the command. In the Laravel Sail environment, the user is typically `www-data`.

```yaml
php-queue:
    restart: always
    image: sail-8.0/app:latest
    user: www-data
    command: 'php artisan queue:work'
    volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/html'
```

This will run the `php artisan queue:work` command as the `www-data` user, which should exist in your Docker image.